# Restrict event booking to those with a code

Tags: civievent

I want to allow a particular set of people to book an event before opening it up to anyone. If these were all members, then there are various ways to do this (e.g. the member only event extension) but that won't work (the CRM is still under development, memberships not up to date and we don't want to chase at present because of coronavirus). We do have all these people in a group, but they don't have accounts and getting them to log into accounts is also going to be messy so what I've done elsewhere with ACLs is also going to be hard to manage.

What I would like to do is issue a booking code to this group and only allow booking with the code. I'd thought I might be able to do this with CiviDiscount, but its a different use case! The best I can think of is have the booking via a web page listing the events which is password protected. Probably enough security for this, but not elegant!

Any other suggestions? I'm on WordPress.

Comment: a caldera form?

Comment: I expect I might be able to do it that way, but I think the learning curve is too steep for the time I have.

Comment: We've now decided to open booking up to all straight away so we don't need it urgently and so probably can use membership to make the restriction in the future (or find time to learn caldera forms.